# check if key exists in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays in php (codeigniter) code and i would like to check if the value of one of the arrays exists in the second array.

Here is what I am trying:

```
$filters = $this->categoriesFiltersModel->get();        
foreach($filters as $f=> $val) {           
    echo $val['filterid'] ."<br />";           
}

$formValues = $this->input->post(NULL, TRUE);
foreach($formValues as $key => $value) {
    echo " Key: " . $key . "</br>";
}

$search_array = array($f['filterid']);
if (array_key_exists($key, $search_array)) {
    echo "use query 1";
} else {
    echo "use query 2";
}

die();
```

First array returns values like:

1
2
3
4
....

and the second
field1
field2
field3

so I am expecting use query 1 to be printed here, however, no matter what i do, i always get use query 2 printed. Anyone can point what i am doing wrong?

Regards, John

Comment: are you comparing 1,2,3 to field1, field2, field3 ? what's $f outside the first foreach?

Comment: yes, that is what i am comparing. f can be removed if that is the problem

Comment: not only $f outside, but it's a key actually, $val has the 'filterid'. Some serious restructure here..

Comment: i tried different things in last couple of hours...nothing worked. how would you restructure it?

Comment: basically if any of the $key exists in the $serach array, i should return use query 2, else i should get use query 1...

Comment: Hi actually what are trying to compare? Are you trying to compare against `$filters` against post values?

Comment: i am trying to compare $filter['filterid'] with $key from post array.

Comment: but they're not the same things: key = fieldX and filterId = 1 ... If you look for the key, it won't match

Answer (score 0):

**use this function instead of array_key_exist()**

```
function array_ikey_exists($key,$arr)
{
    $e = 0; //$key = addslashes($key);
    if(is_array($arr) && $arr !==array())
    {
        foreach($arr as $k => $v)
        {   
            if(strtolower($k) == strtolower($key))
                $e++;
        }
        if($e>0)
            return true;       
        else
            return false;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: I use codeigniter, and i am already within a function...can't this be done somehow simplier?

Comment: Make it a protected function within that class?

Answer (score 0):

The problem I see is that the array is not being set on the search array, the search array should have the correct key in there. If you just do it like you did, the key of the array starts at 0. The other problem could be that if the value of $key is 'field1' it wont match either cause that would then need to be an associative array that is to be searched.

```
$filters = $this->categoriesFiltersModel->get();        
foreach($filters as $f=> $val) {           
    echo $val['filterid'] ."<br />";           
}

$formValues = $this->input->post(NULL, TRUE);
foreach($formValues as $key => $value) {
    echo " Key: " . $key . "</br>";
}

$search_array = array($key => $f['filterid']);
if (array_key_exists($key, $search_array)) {
    echo "use query 1";
} else {
    echo "use query 2";
}

die();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `array_keys` and `in_array`. Try:

```
$formValues = $this->input->post(NULL, TRUE);
$keys = array_keys($formValues);

$result= array();
$filters = $this->categoriesFiltersModel->get();        
foreach($filters as $f=> $val) {           
    if(in_array($val['filterid'],$keys)){
           $result[] = $val['filterid'];
    }            
}
```

Now `result` array will hold the matched elements.

See demo [here](https://eval.in/103195)